# Number of tokens attribute in Cassandra YAML

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Is there any significance to the value used in the 'number of tokens' attribute in the Cassandra's YAML file if all the nodes have got the same value in their respective YAML files? Is it the relative value that makes the difference? For e.g. is there any difference, whatsoever, in the below 2 scenarios(assume a cluster of n nodes):

- Case 1: Number of tokens is set as 256 in each of the n nodes.
- Case 2: Number of tokens is set as x where x is different than 256 in each of the n nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This value can affect how good data is distributed between nodes - the bigger value is, the more uniform data distribution will be.  But this comes at cost of additional overhead because Cassandra will need to maintain all these virtual nodes.  Depending on the number of virtual nodes & replication factor, the distribution may vary - for example, for RF=3 & vnodes=8, distribution may vary by ~10%.  The recommendation could also different for different versions of Cassandra - for 3.x, recommendation is from 8 to 32. More information you can find in this [document](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/config/configVnodes.html).

P.S. If you're using DSE, you may also tweak the `allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor` for better allocation of data.

Comment: I'm using Apache Cassandra 3.11.2 and couldn't find "allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor" in the default YAML file. Should I add this manually or was it absent because it was not supported?

Comment: Ah, sorry - that's DSE-specific flag, I didn't check vanilla Cassandra when I wrote about it.

Comment: Is your recommendation of setting num_tokens between 8 to 32 valid for Apache Cassandra as well?

Answer (score 0):

`allocate_tokens_for_local_replication_factor` is specific to DSE

Apache Cassandra has the parameter `allocate_tokens_for_keyspace`

Comment: You might want to add that this is a complement to Alex Ott answer